# Guzzle seems to strip password part from request url

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I'm trying to make a Http request with a url like

```
https://{{api_key}}:{{api_password}}@{{store_name}}.myshopify.com/admin/api/{{api_version}}/products.json
```

But the Http response is throwing `***` replacing the `api_password`, even if I hardcode it.

This is all done in a Laravel app and is failing with `400 Bad Request`.

The request is working using postman.

Is the password actually being stripped out of the request, or is it just being hidden in the response?

Comment: can you elaborate your question what are the steps and procedures you had done. also compare the code from laravel to postman

Comment: I'm doing this in the handle function of a job:
```
 $headers = [
            'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
            'Accept'        => 'application/json'
 ];
        $client = new Client();
        $res = $client->post("https://{{api_key}}:{{api_password}}@{{store_name}}.myshopify.com/admin/api/{{api_version}}/products.json",$headers, json_encode($this->shopifyProduct));
}
```
The response from Postman gives me back the product, the response in Laravel  is the 400 error.

Comment: As in, the laravel error looks like this: `Client error: `POST https://{{api_key}}:***@{{store_name}}.myshopify.com/admin/api/{{api_version}}/products.json` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response`

Comment: what laravel version you're using?

Comment: Laravel 8, Guzzle 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [HTTP CLIENT](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client)

This is how it works:

Import `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;`

```php
Http::post(
"https://${api_key}:${api_password}@${store_name}.myshopify.com/admin/api/${api_version}/products.json",
[
  "foo" => "bar"
]);
```

`Http::post` automatically converts headers to `content-type: application/json`.

**HTTP CLIENT** helps you to make less error and it also using guzzle.

Comment: Yes, this worked. I don't know where I got the idea that using Guzzle was the way to go, but is seems much less error prone.